# Fetch data from csv file: Error IO operation on closed file

Tags: python, csv

### I'm trying to fetch some data from csv file but getting some error

error: ##

> Exception in Tkinter callback
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\hp-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter__init__.py",
>   line 1549, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)
>
> File "C:\Users\hp-\Downloads\pyguii.py", line 120, in combine_funcs
>       recommend()
>
> File "C:\Users\hp-\Downloads\pyguii.py", line 114, in recommend
>       for row in reader:
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\hp-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\csv.py",
>   line 109, in **next**
>       self.fieldnames
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\hp-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\csv.py",
>   line 96, in fieldnames
>
> ```
> self._fieldnames = next(self.reader) ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
> ```

```
def getrate():
    stem=tk.Toplevel(root)
    a1=Label(stem,text='Which type of songs will you like to listen')
    a1.grid(row=0,column=0)  
    var2 = IntVar()
    dd1 = Radiobutton(stem, text="Hindi songs", variable=var2, value=1)
    dd1.grid(row=1,column=1)
    label = Label(stem)  
    dd2 = Radiobutton(stem, text="Punjabi songs", variable=var2, value=2)
    dd2.grid(row=2,column=2)
    label = Label(stem)  


def getcat1():
    gg2=var2.get()
    fields.append(gg2)
    with open(r'category.csv', 'a') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(fields)
    print(gg2)

def recommend():
    with open('listsng.csv') as csvfile:
         reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
         #print (reader)
    for row in reader:
         if '2015' in row['Year'] and 'Hindi' in row['Category']:
             print(row['Song Name'])

def combine_funcs():
    getcat1()
    recommend()
ee=Button(stem,text='Submit',command=combine_funcs)
ee.grid(row=10,column=2)
ee1=Button(stem,text='Skip',command='')
ee1.grid(row=10,column=4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access the `reader` after the file has been closed outside the context it was opened. Move the `for` loop in the `recommend` function into the context of `with`, like so:

```
def recommend():
    with open('listsng.csv') as csvfile:
         reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
         #print (reader)
         for row in reader:
             if '2015' in row['Year'] and 'Hindi' in row['Category']:
                 print(row['Song Name'])
```

---

The `with` statement in Python creates a context, and in this case a context was created for the file object. Once you leave the `with` context, Python closes the file and does some cleanup. Therefore, all operations that relate to the file object must be executed in the context in which the file was opened.